# vb6 Treeview refresh ( show updated file ) in child items

Tags: vb6

I load treeview1 and treeview2 with same zip names but child items maybe different to each other.
now for the sake of the test i loaded treeview2 with few zip names and it has child items to it, instead of reloading the items i used 
`treeview2.refresh`
now leaving the treeview2 items loaded,i open 1 of the zips and add any 1 file in it then going back to treeview2 hit refresh it does not show update unless i reload the items again.

```
TreeView2.Nodes.Clear
ListFiles app.path & "\folder\", "zip"
```

ignore the code above i load my items like this ,how do i refresh the items and show updated items without reloading.

Comment: You don't need to do anything, the TreeView should clear by itself after `TreeView2.Nodes.Clear` and also update when you add new nodes. When you say you add a file, are you adding an actual Tree node or a file in the Zip file itself?

Comment: i load the zip files as usual into treeview2 and manually add 1 file into the zip file and going back to the app pressing refresh on treeview2 to se if child items update with newly file added but it dont show the new child item, to confirm i manually add 1 file to the zip file and not in app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are adding the files to the Zip files through your app, you will have to monitor the content or DateLastModified of the Zip files yourself. You can create a subroutine to iterate through your Zip file names, check their content/DateLastModifed and adjust the nodes in your TreeView. You can call this subroutine on a Timer if the contents of your Zip files changes frequently.

Here's an example of an approach that uses a Dictionary to track each file's LastModifiedDate:

```
Dim m_objFileModifiedDates As New Dictionary
Dim m_objFSO As New FileSystemObject

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objFile As File
    Dim sModifiedFiles As String

    Set objFolder = m_objFSO.GetFolder("C:\temp\")

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        ' Check if it exists in Dictionary
        If Not m_objFileModifiedDates.Exists(objFile.Name) Then
            ' Add File
            m_objFileModifiedDates.Add objFile.Name, objFile.DateLastModified
        Else
            ' Check Last Modified Date
            If m_objFileModifiedDates.Item(objFile.Name) <> objFile.DateLastModified Then
                ' Update Dictionary
                m_objFileModifiedDates.Item(objFile.Name) = objFile.DateLastModified
                sModifiedFiles = sModifiedFiles & objFile.Name & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If

    Next

    If sModifiedFiles <> "" Then
        ' Update TreeView with modifed files
        MsgBox "Files modified: " & vbCrLf & sModifiedFiles
    End If

End Sub
```

When this detects a file has been modified, you can update your TreeView by reading the modified file's content again and update that TreeView Node, or simply update the whole tree.

Comment: You can use a Dictionary object to keep track of all your Zip files and store their LastModified DateTime. This would greatly speed up checking if files have changed.

Comment: What does the Refresh button you are clicking do?